# What is $S^n$ minus $n$ points homeomorphic to?

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is $S^n$ minus $n$ points homeomorphic to?

I already know that $S^n$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via stereographic projection, so I'm very tempted to say that $S^n$ minus $n$ points is just homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus $n-1$ points.

Comment: That sounds like good intuition

Comment: Your surmise is perfectly correct.

Comment: It seemed way too simplistic to be correct and I tried for a long while to try and fault it, but I can't say that I'm upset that it is correct! Thanks for the confirmation - if either of you would like to post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Your answer is correct. note that a sphere minus two points is a cylinder. I wonder if there is something similar for an $n$-sphere minus $n$ points.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I recall doing something similar, but only for the $S^2$ case and with explicit functions. I know it's slightly off topic, but how would that work geometrically?

Comment: I don't know - I was purely speculating.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry if it wasn't obvious, but I meant for $S^2$ minus two points being a cylinder rather than $S^n$ minus $n$ points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. As $S^n\setminus{\{p_1\}}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a homeomorphism $\varphi:S^n\setminus{\{p_1\}}\to\mathbb{R}^n$. If you want to extract also $p_2,\ldots,p_n$ just notice that $\tilde{\varphi}:=\varphi|_{S^n\setminus\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}}$ must be a homeomorphism between $S^n\setminus\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{\varphi(p_2),\ldots,\varphi(p_n)\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the "just notice that..." part, I didn't think of looking at it that way.

Comment: Is that sarcasm? It is not obvious that $\tilde{\varphi}$ and $\tilde{\varphi}^{-1}$ must be continuous?

Comment: Not at all. The geometric intuition worked for me, but if I were to write down an explicit proof, the restriction of the initial homeomorphism would be what I really want, and I hadn't thought of that at all.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry for the confusion, I just wanted to know if you needed me to write it down more precisely.:)